# How to make specific columns of a csv file read only with php

Tags: php, csv

I wrote a script to export some columns(id and name) of a mysql table so that scores of students can be inserted. But I want to make the id and name columns read only.  I searched but could not find a solution. Please, how can I do this?

Comment: The CSV format is actually a specific formatting inside a plain text file, for which you can hardly place any restriction on. The situation could be different if you were exporting in MS Excel format, where you can "lock" some cells and assign a password protection. But even that can be worked around pretty easily, if the user really wants to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot do this.**

A file is just a stream of bytes stored (in HDD/memory). You read these bytes and interpret it as you want. In case of csv file you read one line and the split this based on separator.

The concept of read only comes from OS. Where you mark a file as read only to ensure users without proper permission do not edit the file.

While writing a program you open a file in read only mode using `r` option this is just a way of telling you do not intend to write anything to file and `fwrite` should not be allowed (throw exception) on this stream.

**What you are asking is to make certain bytes of the files to be read only while others should be editable. OS or file stream have no way differentiating between the two.**